# General lack of cognitive empathy disorder

Tags: cognitive-development, dsm

Has there ever been a documented case or classification of a disorder where a person is unable to comprehend the fact that others do not know the same things they do, or that individuals do not know the same things as each other? From my basic knowledge this sort of understanding usually develops along with self-recognition in childhood, and I am wondering whether there are any people who grow to adulthood without ever achieving this developmental milestone.

For example, the hypothetical person drinks some water and places the cup in a random place that cannot be seen, someone then enters and is asked to bring the cup and the person is then confused about why the newly introduced person does not know where the cup is or what cup is even being referred to.

Comment: I believe the thing you are describing a deficit of is called "theory of mind" - basically, the ability to think in terms of other people having minds/being actors in the world, distinct from yourself. Some researchers used to describe autism is an example of a deficit in theory of mind but that's fallen out of favor now. See also https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23358/14382 and lots of other questions here on theory of mind.

Comment: Please ignore my comment, it was made in error.